# How to write text in UITextField and sent text while I'm writting to textField in uiWebview?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

The idea is very simple.

```
    ->UIWebView has opened google.com or some other website, which has textfields
    -->There is textfield.
    --->When I click on it, usually opens keyboard and you can start to write
    ---->But I want, that it shows UITextField, where I can write something, and when I 
finish writing, it should send text to textfield
```

I want that for google spredsheet cells!
I now that, my question has no sence, but is it possible?

Comment: please clear your question with proper scenario

Comment: once you complete the typing, is there any button on the action of which you will send the text?

Comment: Yes I will make go button somowhere in view!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to say, as you type in the `UITextField` the same value should be shown in the textFileds in webview.

You can use `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` delegate of `UITextField`.

For detail look [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField%3ashouldChangeCharactersInRange%3areplacementString%3a).

Comment: Nice to see u after a long tym on SO.

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary: got free time after a long 6-8 months :)